# Sharepoint portal running slowly SP2007 MOSS2007

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-server, application-pool

Recently my SharePoint portal was randomly running slowly(loading pages and opening documents etc.) I recycled the application pool for the portal and paused the full crawl. Which seemed to fix the issue. However I want to investigate further into why it went slow and if there is a cause that might reoccur.

Can anyone give me any ideas of what to investigate etc.?

Comment: Are there relevant entries in Event Viewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

their are many things which cause the slowness.You can start from here.

- check the memory usage on the WFE.
- Check the CPU usage
- Check the DB server Perfomance
- Check the ULS logs and see if their is any query which is taking too much time.
- optimzed the page, if you have customization
- Use Fiddler to troubleshoot it.
- You also check the Search crawl logs and Server Perfomance while it running.
- Check if more than normal traffic on the servers.

Did you install the any updates on the server recently.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721591.aspx

http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint/10-reasons-why-sharepoint-performance-can-slow

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the Crawl logs and see if there are any issues with Search Crawling.

Also you can use Wake Up Script and schedule it to run every morning. This will warm up SharePoint and make it perform better.